# how to fix reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value error?

Tags: python

When I am trying to find factorial using below code, it is working for all numbers except '0'. When I give the input as 0, below error is displayed. Can some one help me to understand and fix the error

```
from functools import reduce

n = int(input())
fact = lambda a, b: a*b if (n>=1) else 1
reduce(fact, range(1,n+1))
```

Expected result: When input is given as '0' 1 should be displayed as output

Actual result: Below error is displayed

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)    
<ipython-input-124-52f472210976> in <module>    
      3     
      4 fact = lambda a, b: a*b if (n>=1) else 1    
----> 5 reduce(fact, range(1,n+1))    
      6 

TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

Answer (score 7):

In Python 3, at least, `reduce()` has an "initializer" parameter, which "is placed before the items of the sequence in the calculation, and serves as a default when the sequence is empty" ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html)). So use an initializer of `1`. You can also simplify your code by using the multiplication operator in the `operator` module.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

result = reduce(mul, range(1,n+1), 1)
```

You should understand your error now. The error message says that you tried to use `reduce()` on an `empty sequence with no initial value`. Putting in the initial value of `1` solves that.

Comment: The same is in pyhon2. The documentation of python2.7.15 says exactly the same stuff about the "initializer" parameter.

Comment: @Valentino: Thanks for the additional information. I didn't bother to look that up for Python 2, partly because `reduce()` there is in a different module (it's a default function).