# Is reduce method requiring initializer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to append an arbitrary number of PySpark dataframes together.
This is attempted with the `union_all` function below:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame


def union_all(*dfs):
    return reduce(DataFrame.union, dfs)
```

When evaluated, it returns a `TypeError`:

`TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value`

The following thread covers the same `TypeError` but for a different case (lambda function on a range of integers):

[how to fix reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53997025/how-to-fix-reduce-of-empty-sequence-with-no-initial-value-error/53997179)

From that discussion, a solution was to provide an initializer to the `reduce` function.
In my case, this could be a PySpark dataframe, so I use the first element in my list of dataframes:

```
def union_all(*dfs):
    return reduce(DataFrame.union, dfs, dfs[0])
```

Invoking the above function throws an `IndexError`:

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

What does this mean, and how might it be solved ?

The data I am using (`dfs`):
Each element in `dfs` is a dataframe, with the same columns in the same order (there are 3 dataframes in total). This it one of the dataframes as example:

```
DataFrame[id: bigint, index: int, sn: string, sid: string, dt: string, ps: string, fr: string, hr: 
 string, pn: string, aid: string, mf: string, mn: string]
```

Comment: It means that `dfs` is empty. Please provide the line where you call `union_all` function.

Comment: put `print(dfs)` at the beginning of your function - that will show you what dfs contain. most likely it contains nothing.

Comment: I suspect, it should be: `reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y), dfs)` as `union` is called on a df object and second is passed as argument. In the way you implemented it, i think `reduce` might attempt to do smth like `union(x, y)` instead.

Comment: @go2nirvana Well calling method through class is fine, but you need to pass the `self` parameter explicitly first. This means that `DataFrame.union(x, y)` is the same as `x.union(y)` (as long as `x` is of type `DataFrame`)

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych you're right. Have never used instance methods outside instance. That's new, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are passing empty sequence to union_all function as `dfs` argument. Initial value is included in the sequence as a first element for reduce operation.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

> If the optional initializer is present, it is placed before the items
> of the iterable in the calculation, and serves as a default when the
> iterable is empty.

So when you provide empty sequence, if you do not want to got any error you must specify initializer so in this case it corresponds an empty dataframe. However, it is meaningless beacuse you don't have schema information to create appropiate dataframe. So, probably it is better to validate the given parameter has value and  check the given dataframes have the same schema for union operation. Example;

```
from functools import reduce

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# example schema
struct = StructType()
struct.add("a", "integer")
struct.add("b", "integer")
struct.add("c", "integer")

# example dataframes
df_1 = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data=[(1, 2, 3), ], schema=struct)
df_2 = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data=[(10, 20, 30), ], schema=struct)
df_3 = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data=[(100, 200, 300), ], schema=struct)


def union_dfs(*dfs):
    if not dfs:  # check dfs tuple is non-empty
        raise ValueError("At least one dataframe must be provided")

    schemas = [df.schema for df in dfs]
    if len(set(schemas)) != 1:  # validate all dfs have the same schema
        raise ValueError("Each of df's schema must be the same")

    result_df = reduce(DataFrame.union, dfs)

    return result_df

union_df = union_dfs(df_1, df_2, df_3)

union_df.show()

+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
| 10| 20| 30|
|100|200|300|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks, @sagmansercan . It turned out the `dfs` were empty. Your error handling helped me to see it.